# ExtJS.data.store.load empty value outside of callback

Tags: javascript, callback, extjs4, store

Would you please help me take a look codes below? Why I'm unable to get the value outside of callback?

Any comments would be appreciated.

```
var i = 0;
        var myModulesName = []; 
        me.store.load({callback: function(){
                me.store.data.each(function(records) { 
                        if(records.raw.hasLeaf === true){
                            //Ext.Function.defer(function() {
                                myModulesName[i] = records.raw.name;
                                console.log('this is constructor App.js  inside storeload  '+myModulesName[i]);
                            //}, 100, me);
                            ++i;
                        }
                });

            }
        });
        //empty here.
        console.log('this is constructor outside of load    '+myModulesName);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This piece of codes located in a constructor function and I have another function called init() which will be fired after constructor. And the codes below is at the end of my constructor.

```
    if (Ext.isReady) {
            Ext.Function.defer(me.init, 10, me);
        } else {
            Ext.onReady(me.init, me);
}
```

I just moved this part into load() and at the end of 'each' part and it worked! I'm able to get modulesName now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is empty and it will stay empty because the `store.load()` is asynchronous. The request is sent to the server and execution immediately continues. When server returns a response (it may take several seconds) the callback is executed and, if the request was successful, load event is fired.

Comment: Thank you, Saki! How could I be able to get myModulesName outside of load callback? I've even tried set async:false in the definition of my store, nothing changed.

Comment: I don't know what should be the final result. If you want just an array of values received from the server you may not need the store at all. Stores are to provide data source for grids, trees, combos for filtering, sorting, etc. If you don't need that, just send `Ext.Ajax.request`, decode the result and you're done.

Comment: I do need to filter,sort for my tree-like menu. I'm afraid I should have to figure it out. Someone said using callback.call in a getJSON function in another thread. It won't work for store.load.

Comment: I don't know what do you expect. Store load is asynchronous so you need to place all processing that needs data from the server in success callback.

Comment: Thank you Saki. I need to pass data to a variable during load process and after it's successful I'm able to get data outside of load.

Comment: I've set async:false in my store definition, why doesn't it change anything? Could it be a bug or something?

Comment: In Extjs4, I'm able to create an instance of store by using keywords new and then I need to load data and filter and pass them to different variables. That's all I expect. Even I move the code above to the definition of my Store, it's the same. My question is when load event is firing why I'm unable to get data during the process. Why is it empty when load event is done? My Store instance is initialized in parent class and I'm even unable to get store data in child class. The code above always gets executed at the very last my App. Why?